# R Markdown automated plots loop

Tags: r, loops, ggplot2

I'm trying to handle automated loops to create plots in R but I'm a beginner and I'm really struggling with it.

Lets say I have a dataframe like this:

```
lp     date     cars       laptops
1   2016-10-01  bmw         lenovo
2   2016-10-02  mercedes    dell
3   2016-10-03  mercedes    dell
4   2017-11-04  null        acer
5   2017-11-05  seat        asus
6   2017-11-06  seat        asus
7   2018-12-07  bmw         null
8   2018-12-08  volvo       asus
9   2018-12-09  volvo       dell
10  2018-12-10  null        lenovo
```

And after that I use this code:

```
df %>% mutate(date = year(date)) %>% group_by(date, cars) %>% count() -> df_mutated
```

So I get something like:

```
date    cars        n
2016    bmw         1
2016    mercedes    2
2017    null        1
2017    seat        2
2018    bmw         1
2018    volvo       2
2018    null        1
```

After that I use some functions to create two types of plots

```
#gg plot function #
function.name <- function(df_mutated)
{
  require(ggplot2)
  p <- ggplot(df_mutated, aes(x = date, y=n))
  p + geom_bar(stat = "identity",aes(fill = cars))
}
#use of function#
plot_cars <- function.name(df_mutated)

#ggplot with 100% percentage#
function.name2 <- function(df_mutated)
{
  require(ggplot2)
  p <- ggplot(df_mutated, aes(x = date, y=n))
  p + geom_bar(stat = "identity",position = "fill",aes(fill = cars))+scale_y_continuous(labels = percent_format())
}
#use of percentage function#
plot_cars_percentage <- function.name2(df_mutated)
```

In above example I'm creating two different plots for 'date' and one categorical variable = 'cars'. I would like to automate the process, so I can create these two plots for each categorical variable I will have in my dataset, so in this case it would be cars and laptops. Of course in a way that doesn't require writing variable names manually. So in the end I will have much more plots of course as there will be 2 plots per categorical variable.

I'd appreciate any help.
thanks!

Comment: Maybe it's possible to use [`facet_wrap`](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Facets_(ggplot2)/) instead of loop? Simplifies everything... Try to add this `+ facet_wrap(~ laptops)`

Comment: Maybe I didn't explain it good enough. I want the function to take the variables automatically so I don't have to name them.

Comment: Rework your example since it's not clear what you're asking. Why do you include the percentage plot? From your comment it sounds like you want to loop through different variables to use for the `y` variable in the plots, so make an example based around that.

Comment: In the example I use one 'y' variable to create two types of plots that I need. This is all the code I've got so I've pasted it. Now I want to use these functions (or not, I don't know, maybe they won't fit) to create these 2 types of plots for each categorical 'y' variable I will have in my dataframe, so In the above example it is cars and laptops.

Comment: So you want to define what variable to to use for `y` programmatically: http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/aes_.html

Comment: Yes, so the aes(fill= <variable>) <- there should be a loop or something. BUT as you could see in the post, first I have to mutate the original data frame in order to have what I need for one variable. Therefore changing aes itself wont help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `aes_string` as follows:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)


## Data prep
count_df <- function(df, var) {
  df %>% 
    mutate(date = year(date)) %>% 
    group_by(.dots = c("data", var)) %>% 
    count()
}

## Plot function
plot_df <- function(df, var) {
  ggplot(df, aes(x = date, y=n)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity",aes_string(fill = var))
}

## Putting it all together
count_then_plot <- function(df, var) {
  df %>% 
    count_df(var) %>% 
    plot_df(var)
}

## Final repeat over a list of column names
vars_to_plot <- c("cars", "laptops")

vars_to_plot %>% 
  map(~count_then_plot(var = .), df)
```

As I didn't have the data I haven't run this through but it should give the gist.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'm not sure if it works correctly but this is definitely something I had in mind.

Comment: Try running it with your data?